# Failed to use LLVM libraries on Windows

Tags: windows, llvm

I've been using the LLVM release build from here https://github.com/ziglang/zig/wiki/Building-Zig-on-Windows. When I build a simple cpp file that references to LLVM library, the compiler **crashes**. I'm using x64 `cl` as the compiler.

The command I'm using is roughly: `cl -I <llvm include directory> main.cpp %libs% /link /LIBPATH:<llvm lib directory>`

The `%libs%` variable is set to be the output of `llvm-config --libnames all --system-libs`

Below is the simple CPP program I used.

```
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Type.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"

using namespace llvm;

LLVMContext TheContext;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean, `cl.exe` crashes? Show the error, then. How are we supposed to help you without even knowing what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem in my batch script where there's whitespace in the path.